# Creates ball clockwise or anti clockwise

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rotation, geometry, angle

[image]

### Create balls

1. if bar moving towards point A (clockwise),create ball on direction of B (anticlockwise).
2. if bar moving towards point B (anticlockwise),create ball on direction of A (clockwise).

Here is my existing code

```
var randomRotation:Number;          

randomRotation = randomRange(_bar.rotation - randomRange(150,250),_bar.rotation + randomRange(150,250));
ball.rotation = randomRotation;
ball.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5;
ball.y = stage.stageHeight * 0.5;
```

### Bar movement

1. move towards the shortest radius.

Here is my existing code

```
var angleDiff:Number = 180 - Math.abs(Math.abs(_bar.rotation - ball.rotation) - 180);
var angleDiffPlus:Number = 180-Math.abs(Math.abs((_bar.rotation+speed)-ball.rotation)-180);
var angleDiffMinus:Number = 180-Math.abs(Math.abs((_bar.rotation-speed)-ball.rotation)-180);

if (angleDiffPlus < angleDiff)
{
    dr = 1;
}
else if (angleDiffMinus < angleDiff)
{
    dr = -1;
}
else
{
    _bar.rotation = ball.rotation;
}

_bar.rotation +=  speed * dr;
```

So how can those problem can be solve.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Problem is not clear

Comment: i want to creates ball in a certain rotations and i mentions what are conditions to do that

Comment: I did not understand these conditions and "existing code" shows `bar` setting, not `ball`

Comment: yep really unclear ... +Close for now. What is the problem exactly? you do not know if the bar is moving CW/CCW or you do not know how to obtain ball position ? (which is btw. not described at all in your question)  or what? is the ball moving and you want to control/balance the speed&direction of it instead?

Comment: Why not make a short animated GIF to illustrate expected result? The "1" in centre should also become "2" to show expected condition 2 animation... Does _"create ball on direction of..."_  mean that as `bar` moves then **multiple** `ball`s should be created (added to canvas?) or is this about always moving one ball opposite to current direction on bar?

Comment: Are you trolling? 1. what is `bar`? 2. How is it moving towards A/B? 3. What means "create ball on direction of"? 4. What means "move towards the shortest radius"? Radius is distance from center of a circle to its edge. How can you move towards a distance?

Comment: @PawełAudionysos exactly about "shortest radius of a circle"..!! He is using Flash which also makes **animation**. He could easily use 5 minutes to make a moving example and say _"I want to achieve this movement by code"_ that would explain better than his confusing English. No offense, but he doesn't care so now I vote to close.

Comment: How to vote to close? :)

Comment: @PawełAudionysos you need to have rep for that that would open more options under question (like share,edit,close,reopen, flag ,delete, protect ...)

Comment: if you play the game called "pop the lock" then you will understand what i want to do.i just want to creates balls like that game